# Code::Blocks 20.03 + MinGW bug? "Entry point could not be located in the dynamic link library", but target is an exe console app

Tags: c++, codeblocks, doctest

I am creating a suite of small unit test projects using Code::Blocks IDE bundled with MINGW and doctest as the unit test framework. Under Code::Blocks v17.12, everything builds and runs as expected, but the debugger does not work in the IDE. So I tried an upgrade to v20.03. Now the debugger works in the IDE, but I can't make an EXE that runs. Builds of both debug and release versions are clean. The project is defined as a C++ console application. An attempt to run the Release exe file from a Windows command console produces the error message: "The procedure entry point __cxa_thread_atexit could not be located in the dynamic link library ...\SetGetBitTest.exe."

Why does Code::Blocks 20.03 build something in an exe target file that Windows command window thinks is a DLL? This seems to be a Code::Blocks bug. Could a complicating factor be use of doctest, which embeds all executable code in doctest.h, and doctest.cpp is an empty shell? The main() function for the test is in the unit test source file, as prescribed by doctest. Again, this works fine under Code::Blocks v17.12. I have searched for other reports where a release build 10.03 exe file produced by Code::Blocks 20.03 has produced this error, and found only a couple of cases where the build target WAS a DLL.

Has anyone else run into a similar problem, and been able to resolve it?

Comment: It's not a mingw bug. I expect you have more than 1 version of the mingw runtime in the folders of your `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: What I mean by the above comment is your code is compiled by one version of mingw but when you go to execute it the dlls for the runtime libraries for a different version of mingw were found in one of the folders of the `PATH` environment variable and used instead of the ones you used with your current compiler.

Comment: drescherjm - Great comment. I removed the only MINGW entry from the path environment variable. Code::Blocks defines its own path to MINGW in the toolchain executable settings, so does not use environment variables to find MINGW tools. And MINGW should not come into play when executing a stand-alone EXE console app. After restart and rebuild, there was no difference either in the build process or in the failure to execute the EXE. So the investigation continues...

Comment: I updated doctest to the latest version 2.4.6 in case something in doctest was causing confusion about what kind of executable product is in the EXE file. That also made no difference in the ability to execute a release build EXE. Windows still apparently thinks it is trying to execute a DLL named *.exe.

Comment: ***“Entry point could not be located in the dynamic link library”*** indicates the DLL conflict I mentioned. If you still have this error you need to check into your `PATH` environment variable for possible conflicting versions of mingw or its runtime.

Comment: At the time of my first post, I had no entries in the Windows path environment variable for any version of MinGW. I added the path to the MinGW installation bundled with Code::Blocks 20.03. There was no difference in symptom. I still think it is a clue that instead of citing the DLL that cannot be found or executed, the error message indicates that it failed to find entry point __cxa_thread_atexit IN THE EXE. __cxa_thread_atexit runs destructors at end of program execution, and normally resides in libstd++-v6.dll, which is in the MinGW path.

Answer (score 0):

I turned on the option static libstdc++ in Code::Blocks Compiler settings. It fixed the execution error on failure to find entry point __cxa_thread_atexit. All is good now.